# Trouble with eclipse and JRE/JDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've downloaded everything. I've got the ADT bundle from the developer site properly downloaded. I have the SDK tools downloaded and properly installed as well. When I start up eclipse, it tells me it cannot locate a JRE or JDK file.

At first, I went back to the website and it said to run the SDK tools executable file and it will automatically find and install the JDK file along with it. When you execute, it brings up a little box and in the box it says it has in fact detected a JDK and it will install it too.

I've tried reinstalling and redoing this in many different ways, but nothing will work. Can someone point me in another direction or tell me a solution?

Thanks in advanced.

****EDIT****

I've fixed the problem, but I am now encountering a different error message. When I start up eclipse, it gives a message box that says:

Failed to load JNI shared library "path listed"

Man, man, man what do I do? This is extremely disheartening. I have no idea why my software is acting this way. At school, in class - earlier today - all I did was simply follow the instructions on the developer website and installed the SDK bundle to a folder on the desktop class computer and everything worked just fine - like it was supposed.

Please, please help me, someone!

Comment: do you have java/javaw binaries (java.exe/javaw.exe if you are on windows) in the current path?

in the command prompt, does typing java and pressing return display something?

Comment: yeah, I have a java.exe in the PATH. It says this exactly upon starting eclipse:

A JRE or JDK must be available to run eclipse No java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: C:\justin\desktop\eclipse ide\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe javaw.exe in your current PATH

Comment: I installed the SDK bundle from the developer site the exact same way as I did in class today. The only difference is that it actually worked when I fired it up in class. Same environment - windows 64 bit 7.

Comment: What's the name of the missing JNI library?

Comment: @GenXdark i hope you've got this sorted. its not a fix but, 32bit JVM + 32bit Eclipse should work out fine.

Answer (score 0):

You works on Windows?

Did you set you [JAVA_HOME](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows) in your environment variables?

Comment: I'm working with a 64-bit windows 7. I haven't done that. On the developer site , it said all I had to do was download and intall the SDK bundle - which I've done. 

Teach me about JAVA_HOME - what does it mean to set it and how do I do so?

Comment: UPDATE -- Yes, I have set the JAVA_HOME environment variable. All that did was make my computer warn me about high disc usage being cause by a java runtime environment. 

anybody out there please help me out here. I have no idea where to look and everything I read doesn't work.

Comment: Why JNI? You're using Android NDK?

Answer (score 0):

Check your eclipse.ini file -vm arg must point to a valid jvm.dll

Comment: I am unsure of what exactly this means. I can see my .ini file andI can open it, but I have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: I went to the link you provided and learned about -vm and the .ini file. NONE of the solutions offered by manipulating the .ini file worked or even changed anything.